# Computer Problems not sure how to figure out what is going wrong

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

I recently bought a new computer case to replace my old one since it was breaking. I bought the case and put everything into it. After I went through that painful process I noticed that door on the case was broken and I had to take everything out and return it and get a non broken one.

So I put everything back in and the computer loaded fine and I had it on for at least 3 to 4 hours(just running) and it was all fine. The next day I came and loaded my computer up it would take like 20mins to get into windows 15mins to load up the desktop icons.

I ran the seagate hardrive checker and it came back with that my harddrive was broken. I opened the case and checked the connections and plugged the harddrive into a different sata port in the motherboard.

Everything seemed to work I ran the seagate tool multiple times and it passed it every single time as opposed of failing it everytime before my little fix.

Because of this I had to load up windows from the windows 7 dvd as my boot was corrupted and I had to use the bootsec command to get that back.

After that everything worked fine(it did seem slower) but it worked.

Then yesterday I turned on my computer and walked away. When I came back it seemed like my computer restarted itself or went into sleep mode but whatever it did I could not get back into windows.

Now my computer is really messed up. Everytime I try to load into windows I get something like  "bootdisk failed please insert cd".

I try to load up the windows dvd and it takes forever. I get into the screen where the menu options are but all I see is my mouse. I don't actually see the menu. I don't know if it is just exteremly slow or what.

So I thought ok I will use one my backups(norton ghost) and start from that point maybe a few weeks back. I pop in the norton ghost book it from the dvd and it starts to load and it takes forever.

It will get past the "loading files part" and get to the screen where it looks like windows 7 would be loading. It just hangs on this one and then I get a blue screen saying that it prevented my computer from getting any damage.

It gives many different thing why it could happen. Not enough storage space, something about the bios setting and etc.

So I am not sure what to do. Is it my harddrive? Or maybe I messed my motherboard up I don't know.

Comment: I doubt it read "Your hard drive is broken". What was the specific error condition it mentioned? Additionally I take it you took care to ensure grounding post placement when you put your mobo in that case.

Comment: Yes I took care of grounding. There was really no specific error at the end of the blue screen it had like some technical info that looked like hex numbers or something like that.

Comment: Anyway to replicate or get those back? Those hex values can add meaning.

Comment: Should be able to. I can just try to load up norton ghost through the cd it should crash.

Answer (score 2):

Checking all your hardware to insure cards and cables are well-seated is a good start (with power off, of course)

I suggest removing all extra cards/peripherals but the essentials, and seeing if the system is stable.  If it is, then add them in one at a time to see if you can isolate the behavior.

Given that you are having slow system behavior even when booting from DVD, you may be having some issues with your system memory.  You can (on another computer) download the [MemTest+](http://www.memtest.org/) utility, and extract it to a CD.  This is a self-booting utility that you let run for a few hours (or overnight) and will report any memory failures in your system.

If that is OK, then you might also check your hard disk with chkdsk, or a HD recovery utility such as [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Ok finally got norton ghost to load(all of sudden it just loaded up). So I been able to make backups of the drives(so I can get files off it later) and now have formated the entire drive and reinstalled windows. I think one problem is windows was messed. The file system time was unknown when it should have be NTFS. I ran the windows memory test and it came back clean. I want to do more tests now. So any other software that I can use to test?

Comment: That's good - did you run MemTest+, or some other memory checking tool?  Prime95 is another good testing tool to stress-test your CPU, and verify that it is stable (especially important if you suspect overheating, or if you've overclocked the system.)

Comment: As I mentioned I ran the windows 7 memory tool and nothing was found.

Comment: MemTest+ is quite a bit more thorough than the WMD tool, so it's still worth running.  If you get through MemTest+ and Prime95, and chkdsk runs successfully, you've got solid memory, CPU, and disk.  After that you can start looking at broader benchmark tools, such as the SiSoftware Sandra tools, PC Wizard (www.cpuid.com), PCMark, 3DMark, and others.